# How i over come with name error in python

Tags: python, file, compiler-errors, namespaces, raw-input

i wrote following code but during run its gives name error in 'raw_input' please help me to out of this

my code is:`fname = raw_input('enter a file name: ')
            print (fname)`

Error is= name error:name 'raw_input'is not define

Comment: You are using Python 3, where `raw_input` has now been changed to simply `input`

Comment: Looks like you use Python 3 where `raw_input` doesn't exist. Replace it with `input` or switch back to Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` on python 3+ is now just `input()`

```
fname = input('Enter a file name: ')
print(fname)
```